# How to use java in cmd to get a stable output?

Tags: visual-c++, jvm

It sounds a strange question, but there is a reason.

I'm working to use VC++ code auto find out the max memory that JVM can use . I want to use java cmd to launch JVM simply.

My thoughts was:

Running `java -Xmx3999G -version` like commands and the output, if the JVM is launched successful, there will be something like

> java version "1.8.0_45"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Otherwise it will output something like

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to allocate
>
> 131039232KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the r equested
>
> 4193255424KB heap. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Now the key is that how to know whether the JVM is launched or not ? I can find some keywords in output like `java version` to get know it launched. But the output would be unstable if java update or something else.

The stable way I can think out is running a java code which has unchanged output (just print a simple string in main function can do this). But it needs me to package a jar file in my project's `rc` and extract it to temp folder and run it in cmd. I think it is little complex.

So I'm asking for help here , can any java command gives me a stable output if JVM is launched ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `java -help`? Its output would always contain a list of commands, which surely contains a stable subset.

Other than that, you may still decide to retest once a new JDK version appears. It is imho highly unlikely that there are bigger changes in the output. Here's the output from java version 1.6.0_45:

> java version "1.6.0_45"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>
> 1.6.0_45-b06) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

and here from java version 1.7.0_75:

> java version "1.7.0_75"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

These look very similar to 1.8.x except for the version number itself.

Comment: How to get know the output is from `java -help` not other things ? Just find whether `java [-options] class [args...]` is in output ?

Comment: e.g. parse the output line by line and look for substrings like `-cp` and/or `-version`etc.

Comment: Many thanks, I think my demand would be unreasonable, but my boss can not put up with even 1% mistake .

Comment: I think as long as you are restricted to oracle JDKs, you are fine. more exotic JVMs might have other output, but I have no experience on those. If your boss allows for less than 1% mistake, then you should test your algorithm with all JVMs you can grab, i.e. all available Oracle and OpenJDK major versions, or better: let him specify which ones he wants to have. As for future versions, nobody can reasonably expect you to be a fortune teller, you're supposed to be a software engineer.

Comment: I can't agree with you more. If I allow other JVM, running a java code would be better :-(